# How to attach JavaScript event to element in rich-textarea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to attach JavaScript event in creating blog sites which use rich-textarea, "blogger" for example.

I tried to write the following code in the "edit html" tab:

```
<span id="spanID" onclick="alert('yes');">
hello world
</span>
```

I clicked on the "compose" tab and again on the edit html tab and the script event just deleted! The code which left was:

```
<span id="spanID">
hello world
</span>
```

I tried it also in other blog sites and they also deleted my event.

Why is it deleting my code? How can I attach an event to an element?

Comment: If you are trying this on hosted blog sites, then they are probably intentionally removing your JavaScript code because they don't want their users running any such custom scripts.  You won't find a way around it (or if you do, that would be a security hole in the blogging site/software that should be reported), short of hosting your own blog.